# A version of \showhyphens that works with OpenType fonts

Tags: xetex, hyphenation, opentype

In a [2014 post of the XeTeX list](https://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2014-January/025129.html), the Great Master David Carlisle gives the following code for obtaining the same result as with the `\showhyphens` command, but with OpenType fonts in XeTeX:

```
\catcode`\@=11
\def\showhyphenspace#1 {%
\ifx\valign#1\valign\else
#1\vadjust{\penalty\@ne} \expandafter\showhyphenspace
\fi}

\def\showhyphens#1{{%
\showboxbreadth\maxdimen
\showboxdepth\maxdimen
\pretolerance\m at ne\tolerance\m at ne
\setbox2\hbox{}%
\setbox0\vbox{%
\pretolerance\m at ne
\tolerance\m at ne\hbadness\z@
\parfillskip\z at skip
\hsize1sp
\noindent
\hskip\z@
\hfuzz\maxdimen
\hbadness\maxdimen
\showhyphenspace#1 {} \par
\loop
\count@\@ne
\ifnum1=\lastnodetype
 \setbox4\lastbox
 \setbox2\hbox{\unhbox4 \unhbox2}\count@\z@
\fi
\ifnum11=\lastnodetype\unskip\count@\z@\fi
\ifnum13=\lastnodetype
 \count2\lastpenalty
 \unpenalty\count@\z@
 \ifnum\count2=\@ne
 \setbox2\hbox{ \unhbox2}\count@\z@
 \fi
\fi
\ifnum\z@=\count@
\repeat
\hsize\maxdimen
\hfuzz\z@
\hbadness\z@
\par
\unhbox2
\par
}}}
```

When I run this code I get a lot of error messages such as

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\showhyphens ...xdepth \maxdimen \pretolerance \m 
                                                  at ne\tolerance \m at ne \...
l.129 }
```

and

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\showhyphens ...t ne\hbadness \z@ \parfillskip \z 
                                                  at skip \hsize 1sp \noinde...
l.129 }
```

and merely a third of the text that I wanted to see hyphenated.

Could you please tell me what to replace `\z` and `\m` with, so that it works in XeLaTeX?

Comment: You've got an oddly-formatted version: you want for example `\m@ne` not `\m at ne`

Comment: There's a problem in copy-pasting. All `<space>at<space>` bits should be `@`

Comment: Thank you so much! If only all problems were so easy to solve! (Please write an answer instead of a comment, so that I can validate it and you get the well-deserved credit!)

Comment: BTW, with a medium size text (~ 2,000 words) it works smoothly and produces an immediate result. With a 12,000-word text it takes ages and produces nothing. Am I doing something wrong? Or are there some limits not to cross?

Comment: note if you are using xelatex or lualatex then something equivalent to that is the default definition of `\showhyphens` you don't need any extra re-definition.

Comment: @yannis you are putting the entire text into `\showhyphens` ? I don't think either the plain tex or this opentype version were really designed for that: the usual use is to put in one or two words for which you want to see the hyphenatipn?

Comment: OK, I realized that I have to segment a bit better. But still, David, when I use the standard \showhyphens with xetex and an OpenType I get no hyphenation at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are reading a version that has been mangled by a mail or website re-formatting changing `@` to `at` to make email addresses safe from copying...

`\m at ne`  is `\m@ne`  ie `-1`

But you do not need this at all, the default definition of `\showhyphens` in XeLaTeX is the following slightly updated version of that code.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\showhyphens[1]{%
  \setbox0\vbox{%
    \usefont{TU}{lmr}{m}{n}%
    \hsize 1sp %
    \hbadness\@M
    \hfuzz\maxdimen
    \tracingonline\z@
    \everypar={}%
    \leftskip\z@skip
    \rightskip\z@skip
    \parfillskip\z@skip
    \hyphenpenalty=-\@M
    \pretolerance\m@ne
    \interlinepenalty\z@
    \clubpenalty\z@
    \widowpenalty\z@
    \brokenpenalty1127 %
    \setbox\z@\hbox{}%
    \noindent
    \hskip\z@skip
    #1%
    \par
     \loop
     \@tempswafalse
     \ifnum\lastnodetype=11\unskip\@tempswatrue\fi
     \ifnum\lastnodetype=12\unkern\@tempswatrue\fi
     \ifnum\lastnodetype=13 %
      \count@\lastpenalty
      \unpenalty\@tempswatrue
    \fi
    \ifnum\lastnodetype=\@ne
     \setbox\tw@\lastbox\@tempswatrue
     \setbox0\hbox{\unhbox\tw@\unskip\unskip\unpenalty
                   \ifnum\count@=1127 \else\ \fi
                   \unhbox0}%
     \count@\z@
    \fi
    \if@tempswa
    \repeat
   \hbadness\z@
   \hsize\maxdimen
   \showboxdepth\z@
   \tolerance\m@ne
   \hyphenpenalty\z@
   \noindent\unhbox\z@
}}
```

Comment: I like very much your answer and the "Great Master David Carlisle" written by the user. :-) +1